# Как вывести значение COUNT после LEFT JOIN ... WHERE, если отфильтровались все записи

Tags: mysql, postgresql9.6

Есть две таблицы:

```
user(id, name)
event(id, date, user_id)
```

Каждый день для юзера выполняется event и пишется в таблицу.
Как я могу получить список юзеров, для которых **сегодня** event ещё не выполнялся (у юезра может вовсе не быть записей об евенте (новый юзер), либо старые записи. Если у юзера есть событие сегодня, то в выборке он не должен быть).

Пробовал такой запрос, но в итоге выводит не то что нужно:

```
select
  u.name, count(u.id)
from
  "account" as u
  left join event as e on e.user_id=u.id
where
  e.date > '2018-06-28 23:00:00.000 +00:00' or 
  e.date is NULL 
group by u.id
```

Comment: вы в where написали дословно: "дай тех, у кого вообще не было событий и тех у кого они были позднее чем 23 часа 28 июня, т.е. фактически сегодня". Если вам наоборот не нужны те, у кого событий не было сегодня то вероятно надо  у условия с датой поменять знак на противоположный

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```
select
  u.name, count(u.id)
from
  "account" as u
  left join event as e on e.user_id=u.id
where
  e.date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or 
  e.date is NULL 
group by u.id
```

Если нет, то давайте тестовые данные и ожидаемый результат